# DICOM: Is every instance in a series required to have the same set of tags?

Tags: dicom

I am still trying to wrap my head around DICOM, and this is a pretty basic question. I have spent plenty of hours in the standard but I can't find the answer to this question. Is every instance in a series required to have the same set of DICOM tags? And if so, is it also true that every instance in the whole study is required to have the same set of tags?

I realize that every instance is required to conform to an SOP Class, however not all the attributes in a given class are required, leaving open the possibility that some instances may include optional attributes that other instances in the same series do not include. Am I thinking about this the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such requirement imposed by the DICOM standard. However, most systems export acquired data through kind of a pipeline which generates the DICOM format. Thus, it is most often the case that all instances in a series share the same set of DICOM tags.

Comment: Hi, I believe I have the same question. So the standard specifies that for CT series files, each file (CT Image IOD) is required to have the same Modality tag value - i.e. "CT". But that info is buried in appendex (A.1.2.3 Series IE). Is there a way to figure out which tags for two files have to be the same in order to be valid DICOM? I am assuming Patient module has to be the identical for all slices in a study? Thank you!

Comment: It is not quite the same question. And the number of characters allowed for a comment is not sufficient to answer it. If you put a new question, I would try to answer.